# RxJs - waiting for all Observables to finish

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I've got this piece of code:

```
myModel.tags
       .filter(...)
       .map(...)
       .forEach(t => context.dispatch(new MyAction(t)))
```

`dispatch` returns an `Observable`.
I'd like to execute other RxJs code only when those `Observable`s are all completed.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know when all Observables complete you have to collect all of them into an array and then use ideally `forkJoin`:

```
const obs = myModel.tags
  .filter(...)
  .map(...)
  .map(t => context.dispatch(new MyAction(t)))

const done$ = forkJoin(...obs).subscribe(...);
```

The `forkJoin` observable creation method will emit just once with the array of all responses and then complete.